# Civ 5 Hot Seat + Internet Play, is it possible?

Tags: civilization-5

I have two friends that I enjoy playing Civ 5 with, however one doesn't have a computer so he plays Civ 5 with the other friend in a Hot Seat game.  Is it possible to host a game over the internet where a subset of the players play using Hot Seat?

Example:
Player A plays on Computer 1
Player B plays on Computer 2
Player C plays on Computer 2

Player A and Players B + C are connected over the network.

Is there anyway that this is possible in Civ 5?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you mean by host.

You cannot use different methods of multiplayer, so if someone needs hot seat, the entire game needs to use hot seat.  To accomodate, what you would need to do is create the Hot Seat game, and then send the save file back and forth so that each PC can take it's needed turns.  It would boil down to file transfer, whether live through a file share or emailing it back and forth.

That said, [there are websites out there that help make this a lot less onerous than it sounds](http://multiplayerrobot.com/).

Answer (score -1):

Remote Desktop into the computer and all play hotseat.

Comment: Could you elaborate? It's not really clear what you mean.

Comment: It's a badly written answer, but it IS an answer.

Comment: Using remote desktop is a clever solution, but not everyone knows how to do that, or even knows what remote desktop is. I'd suggest giving a short explanation of what it is, and provide a link to an external resource with instructions on how to use Remote Desktop.

Comment: While this technically *will* work, the effort involved in opening up your desktop to RDC into it from anywhere, the vanishingly small odds you would manage to do it securely, and the really bad performance you will get from it all make this a pretty bad option.

Comment: Remote Desktop, afaik, does not work with fullscreen games, so you'd be forced to play in windowed mode.